# Importing a static website on to Kentico CMS

Tags: kentico

I've been developing an static website (just html, css and js files) for a client who now wants to load the site on to Kentico CMS.

I don't know anything about this CMS. Is this a practical way to import the completed code into this system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do things the way Kentico expects.

- Take your header/footer and put them into the master page (template).
- Take individual template HTML and create Layouts and Templates from them.
- Use Kentico Web Part where possible

  - For dynamic content areas, use the Editable Content Web Part.
  - For the menu use the CSS Menu Web Part.
- Use the Portal Engine technique.  Don't use ASPX pages unless you really have to.

Here is some documentation from version 8: https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+portal+engine+master+pages.